# Derivative commuting over integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Can a derivative operation commute over an integral operation irrespective of the properties of the function under the integral ?

Comment: The answer is no. You could read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not in general.  I recommend Gelbaum and Olmsted's *[Counterexamples in Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, which is where I turned to find a counterexample to your question.  Namely, example 15 on page 123 is titled

> A function $f$ for which $d/dx\int_a^b f(x,y)dy\neq\int_a^b[\partial/\partial x f(x,y)]dy$, although each integral is proper.

The example is

$$f(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{-x^2/y} & : y>0, \\
       0 & : y=0, 
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
integrated with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $1$.  Actually, differentiating under the integral sign works here except where $x=0$.

The function and its partial derivative are not jointly continuous.  When they are jointly continuous, differentiation and integration commute.

Comment: the reason is because int_a^b f(x,y)dy is not differentiable at x=0. This can be seen easily by sustituting y = 1/t. I guess the commuting is permitted if and only if the derivative exists. here by derivative i mean that of the integral and not the partial derivative.

Comment: @Rajesh D: No, the integral is differentiable at $x=0$.  The integral is $xe^{-x^2}$ for all real $x$.

Comment: @Jonas: yeah got it, thanks for pointing.

Comment: @Jonas: could you please explain what is 'jointly continous' ?

Comment: @Rajesh: It basically just means continuous on the relevant subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the terminology is to distinguish from "separate" continuity.  The function and its partial are continuous in $x$ for each fixed $y$ and in $y$ for each fixed $x$.  So it's continuous "separately", or "in each variable", but not continuous at $(0,0)$.  As mentioned in the book, one way to see it is not continuous is to approach the point $(0,0)$ along the curve $y=x^2$.

Comment: @Jonas: regarding the last statement in your answer, if the function is not jointly continuous it is imperative that the partial derivative is not jointly continuous.(correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: Not in general.  If you didn't assume separate continuity, for example, you could write down a function that is everywhere discontinuous but constant in $x$ for each fixed $y$, so that the partial derivative is everywhere $0$.  If you mean in addition to assuming continuity in $y$ for each fixed $x$, then I don't know a counterexample off hand, but suspect it is not always true (correct me if I'm wrong).