# Limit of integral - part 2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

Inspired by the recent post "Limit of integral", I propose the following problem (hoping it will not turn out to be too easy). Suppose that $g:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to {\bf R}$ is continuous in both variables separately. Is it true that, for all $x_0 \in [0,1]$,
$$
 \lim \limits_{x \to x_0 } \int_0^1 {g(x,y)\,{\rm d}y}  = \int_0^1 {g(x_0 ,y)\,{\rm d}y} .
$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. In fact, it is related to [Leibniz's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). The counterexample below is from 'Counterexamples in Analysis' and was recently posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8711/derivative-commuting-over-integral/8712#8712) by Jonas Meyer. Consider the function

$$ g(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \left (\frac{3x^2}{y^2} - \frac{2x^4}{y^3} \right)e^{-x^2/y} &  y>0, \\\
       0 & y=0. 
     \end{cases}
   $$

It's easy to see that $g$ is continuous in both variables separately. We have that $\int_{0}^1 g(0,y) dy = 0 $ and $$ \int_{0}^1 g(x,y) dy = e^{-x^2}(1-2x^2)$$ if $ x \ne 0$. So $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \int_{0}^1 g(x,y) dy = 1 \ne \int_{0}^1 g(0,y) dy.$$

Comment: Yes, $g(x,y)$ is the partial derivative of the function $f(x,y)$ given there, and this inequality is precisely why that other example works.

Comment: @Shai Covo: I agree! Joint continuity does not imply continuity, I removed my erroneous answer.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: I ended up  copying some of your LaTeX. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Nuno: Of course I don't. I do that all the time.

Comment: @AD.: I think you meant, "Separate continuity does not imply continuity."  "Joint continuity" is synonymous with continuity.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Yes, that was what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have another counterexample.  Define $f(x)=\int_{0}^x e^{-1/t}dt$ for $x\gt0$.  This is chosen because it goes to zero as $x$ goes to zero from the right and because experimentation led me to the differential equation $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{1}{x^2}$ as a sufficient condition for the following to work.  Define

$$g(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{xy}{f(x)+y^2} & \text{if } x\gt0, \\
       0 & \text{if } x=0, 
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

for $(x,y)$ in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and let $x_0=0$.  The right hand side of your tentative equation is obviously $0$.  The left hand side is 
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{x}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right),$$
which comes out to $\frac{1}{2}$ after $2$ applications of l'Hôpital's rule, if I did it correctly.

(I started by playing with the standard example of a discontinuous but separately continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ when $x$ or $y$ is nonzero, $f(x,y)=0$ when $x=y=0$. Then I tried to see how the $x^2$ in the denominator could be modified to give a counterexample here, by replacing it with an unknown $f(x)$ that goes to $0$ at $0$ and seeing what further properties of $f(x)$ would make it work.  As I mentioned, this led in particular to the sufficient condition $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{1}{x^2}$, and hence to this example.  Unfortunately, I can't offer any real intuition.)

**Added**

I decided to look at this a little more, and came up with an example simpler than the other one I gave.  With $$g(x,y)=\frac{-y}{\log(x/2)(x+y^2)}$$ 
for $x\gt0$ and $0$ otherwise, the same result as above holds.

Comment: Very nice example!

Comment: Nice one! The limit is indeed 1/2.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Your last example is very elegant! Apparently, you meant $\log(x)$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Shai Covo: Thank you.  I did mean $\log(x/2)$, but it makes no difference for getting the left hand side to come out to $1/2$.  I just changed it to $\log(x/2)$ so that we don't have to restrict to $[0,1-\epsilon]\times[0,1]$, a minor technically to accommodate the problem as stated.

Comment: @Shai Covo: But if you prefer, I could change it back to $\log(x)$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: As you remarked, the $\log(x/2)$ is indeed better.

Answer (score 2):

This is true if there is a (measurable) function $f(y)$ such that $$|g(x,y)|\le f(y), \mbox{ for }0\le x\le 1 $$  and $$\int_0^1 f(y)\,dy<\infty.$$
This follows from the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Note: Every continuous function is measurable.

Comment: That is true. Can you find such $f$? :)

Comment: Unless $g(x,y)$ is given, not one can find such $f$.

Comment: In Nuno's example, we have $g(\sqrt{y},y)=e^{-1}/y$, which is not integrable over $(0,1)$.

Comment: @AD. If $g(x,y)$ is continuous, one can take $f$ to be the upper bound of $|g(x,y)|$, so the question is true. In general, one can always use $f(y)=\max_{0\le x\le 1}|g(x,y)|$, but that may be hard to calculate.