# conditions for $\int \frac{df}{dt}dx = \frac{d}{dt} \int fdx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In several literature of partial differential equations I read some arguments as the following:

$$ \int_\Omega \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} dx = \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \int_\Omega f(x,t) dx, $$
where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function. **My question is: what are the sufficient conditions for that the last equality follows? is it always follows?**

Comment: Boundary being fixed is one

Comment: Leibniz's Rule.

Comment: I'd suggest reading this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resu and this for a counter-example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8711/derivative-commuting-over-integral/8712